# Capybara, Poltergeist and Reactjs - 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, reactjs, poltergeist

We started the process of integration `Reactjs` in our Rails 4.1 app. The thing is that a LOT of features are broken now.

Here is the stack for tests:

- Cucumber
- Capybara
- Poltergeist (via phantomjs)
- Rspec

For example, there is the cucumber feature:

```
@javascript @services

Feature: Manage Service
  Scenario Outline: Publish and archieve
    Given the individual user
    When I visit services page
    And I click on I18n translation for key "views.labels.add"
    And I fill service's fields and choose price as "<price>"
    And I click on I18n translation for key "<submit_btn>"
    Then I should see I18n translation for key "<message>"
    And Created service should have 1 tag

  Examples:
    | submit_btn                 | price      | message                                       |
    | views.labels.publish       | fixed      | views.messages.notices.add.created            |
    | views.labels.publish       | negotiated | views.messages.notices.add.created            |
```

When I run this test then I see this error:

```
  One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'RegExp.prototype.test.bind(
      /^(data|aria)-[a-z_][a-z\d_.\-]*$/
    )')
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'RegExp.prototype.test.bind(
      /^(data|aria)-[a-z_][a-z\d_.\-]*$/
    )')
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:32342
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807 in s
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:37581
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807 in s
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:32910
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807 in s
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807 in e
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:47260
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:28807
      at http://127.0.0.1:53686/assets/application.js:47262 (Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError)
  ./features/step_definitions/service.steps.rb:16:in `/^the individual user$/'
  features/service/new.feature:9:in `Given the individual user'
```

Comment: PhantomJS 1.x doesn't have `Function.prototype.bind`. You would need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521), but I don't know how you would use the shim for your particular technology stack. Related: [bind polyfill for PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224323/bind-polyfill-for-phantomjs). In CasperJS you would do this like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359247/casperjs-bind-issue). If you find an answer, don't forget to answer your own question.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution. You need to use [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) for that. I put file in `vendor/assets/javascripts/es5-shim.js`.

After that you need to init this shim. Note that shim should go **BEFORE** the react's init, it is critical!

**application.js**

```
//= require es5-shim
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
```

After that tests started to work again.