# Selenium/PhantomJS doesn't work on http://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/more

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I define a WebDriver, get to an example page: http://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/more/computers/tablets, and click "LoadMore" button for several times. None of them works.

This is how I use it (in scala, I can translate and test in Java if you want):

```
  val baseCaps = new DesiredCapabilities
  baseCaps.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_FINDING_BY_CSS, true)
  baseCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true)
  baseCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, <my binary path>)

val driver = new PhantomJSDriver(baseCaps)

driver.get("http://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/more/computers/tablets")
    val wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    val element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(selector)))
    element.click()
<wait for a few seconds>
val page = driver.getPageSource.getBytes("UTF8")
```

PageSource shows that it is still the page before clicking

Comment: What is the value of `selector`?

Comment: "a.btn", should definitely work

Comment: this is probably related to this bug: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522

Comment: Since I got many of this error: msg: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.renderNextItems.bind(this)')

Comment: What language is this? What language-bindings are you using (please provide a link to documentation)?

Comment: this is Scala, the language binding is GhostDriver: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/412

Comment: I tried with the java bindings to add a [shim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224323/bind-polyfill-for-phantomjs), but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried that as well and failed. Not an expert in javascript shim. Have posted on official github issue tracker