# PhantomJS & Spiderable & Meteor-up issue

Tags: meteor, phantomjs, meteor-up

I'm using meteor-up to setup phantomJS and everything else. It seems to all work, and phantomJS seems to be installed on the server because I can run `phantomjs` which runs the phantomjs console.

However, I am having issues with phantomjs actually getting the title / description of my page.

This is the error I get when I run something like:

`example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=`

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'n[i].bind(this)')

  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:135
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:135
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:135
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:135
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:135 in h
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:517
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:517
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Package["service-configuration"].ServiceConfiguration')

  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:101
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:3
  http://example.com/1fbd069174c2da0b715cdaf4e4551e5d00800cbc.js:3
```

I'm not sure why I get the service-configuration package is undefined. I've never referenced that package. It'd be great if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: PhantomJS 1.x doesn't support `Function.prototype.bind`, you have to use a [shim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224323/bind-polyfill-for-phantomjs). I don't know how this can be done in your case though. In CasperJS it can be done in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25359714

Answer (score 0):

There is still no official PhantomJS 2.0 binary for Linux, so anyone having a troubles with 1.X branch [here](https://github.com/Pyppe/phantomjs2.0-ubuntu14.04x64) is an unofficial 2.0 build.